# Error working with doubles and fmod

Tags: c, double, fmod

Im trying to calculate a power and then a module of big numbers (type double). I want to calcule (1234^79) mod 3337. The result is 901 (Ubuntu's calculator) but function fmod returns 1788.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    double res1;
    double dou = powl(1234.00,79.00);//function for doubles

    printf("Result in double o powl %.3f\n",dou);
    res1=fmod(dou, 3337.00);//doubles

    printf("Result in double of fmod %.2f\n",res1);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Some answer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `powl` expects and returns values of type `long double`. You assign the return value to variable of type `double` only, losing some precision.

Comment: @Gerhardh: I don't think even `long double` precision is going to help in this case ! ;-)

Comment: Replace with repeated calculations. like [this](https://ideone.com/yKFSSE)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : Thank you, your solve save my life :D

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks brother! That saved me as well!

Comment: Note that linked [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927868/error-working-with-doubles-and-fmod#comment80802784_46927868) fails when `a*a` overflows.

Comment: To use modular exponentiation without overflow: [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/29485).

Answer (score 1):

`1234^79` has [245 decimal digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1234%5E79).

`double` only has a precision of around 17 decimal digits.

You need to use a little math to reduce this problem to something that doesn't require arbitrary precision (see [Modular Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)).

(Or just use an arbitrary precision math library + brute force if you aren't interested in an efficient solution.)